# Nothing can be edited in admin panel in magento

Tags: magento

I cannot edit anything in admin panel.

I have magento site ,i logged into the admin panel after that i clicked

cms->page then the pages listed but i cant to edit the page .

When i clicked on the page menu itd displays error in fire bug:

```
TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

33027d...e309.js (line 8281)

TypeError: Fieldset is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Fieldset.addToPrefix(1);

/bc/in...3a06aa/ (line 41)

TypeError: Translate is not a constructor
[Break On This Error]   

...ease use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field...

/bc/in...3a06aa/ (line 44)

ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

...= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; // f...

/bc/in...3a06aa/ (line 49)

ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

Calendar.setup({

/bc/in...3a06aa/ (line 539)

ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

Calendar.setup({

/bc/in...3a06aa/ (line 565)

TypeError: varienGrid is not a constructor
[Break On This Error]   

...d', 'http://localhost/bc/index.php/admin/cms_page/index/key/0681afc112b37ec174e8...
```

And nothing can be loaded correctly displays errors in bug.

And cannot edit anything in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

So verify if your javascript files are even included: view source and see if they are accessible directly. Sometime it can happen if you mistype the nonsecure_base_url